# How to change a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am currently working with an API in python and trying to retrieve previous institution ID's from certain authors.

I have come to this point

```py
my_auth.hist_names['affiliation']
```

which outputs:

```
[{'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '60016491',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60016491'},
 {'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '60023955',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60023955'},
 {'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '109604360',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/109604360'},
 {'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '112377026',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/112377026'},
 {'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '112678642',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/112678642'},
 {'@_fa': 'true',
  '@id': '60031106',
  '@href': 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60031106'}]
```

The type here is list.

I'd like to use this list as a dictionary to retrieve the
`'@id'`
section

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple load the list of dicts as dataframe with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
my_auth.hist_names['affiliation']
df = pd.Dataframe(my_auth.hist_names['affiliation'])
print(df['@id'])
```

In this way you obtain a dataset in which every row is a dictionary of your list, and you can index by column your`'@id'`

with pd.Dataframe(my_auth.hist_names['affiliation']), you obtain

```
   @_fa        @id                                              @href
0  true   60016491  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
1  true   60023955  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
2  true  109604360  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
3  true  112377026  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
4  true  112678642  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
5  true   60031106  http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/af...
```

and for df['@id'], your ids

```
0     60016491
1     60023955
2    109604360
3    112377026
4    112678642
5     60031106
Name: @id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to use [list comprehension,](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which creates a new list based upon elements of an iterable. An implementation using this could be:

```
ids = [item['@id'] for item in my_auth.hist_names['affiliation']]
```

This would create a list that contains each value associated with the `@id` key.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in JSON format, and you can use python's json library to process them.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

```
import json
result_dict = json.load(given_string)
```

Comment: I like this idea, however, I get an error, even when converting from string to list